# How does modifying an array changes another array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want someone to help me understand how does changing the **item** array changes the **orderList** array in the function below?

The function below is used to increment and decrement the quantity of the order
[using "+" and "-" buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SkFm.png), if the action is "+" then add 1 to quantity else minus 1 to quantity

```
        const [orderItems, setOrderItems] = React.useState([])

        const editOrder = (action, menuId, price) => {

        let orderList = orderItems.slice() 
        let item = orderList.filter(a => a.menuId == menuId)

        if(action == "+"){
            if(item.length > 0)
                let newQty = item[0].qty + 1
                item[0].qty = newQty
                item[0].total = item[0] * price
            } else {
                const newItem = {
                    menuId: menuId,
                    qty: 1,
                    price: price,
                    total: price
                }
                orderList.push(newItem)
            }
            setOrderItems(orderList)
        } else {
            if(item.length > 0) {
                if (item[0].qty > 0){
                    let newQty = item[0].qty - 1
                    item[0].qty = newQty
                    item[0].total = newQty * price
                }
            }
            setOrderItems(orderList)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In JS when you assign a value of **object type** (e.g. object literal, array, functions) to a variable say `x`, basically what gets assigned to `x` is a reference to the original value.

If I have

```js
let a = {a: 123}; // _a_ is object
let b = a; // Now _b_ has a reference to it
b.a = 312; // Essentially here we are modifying _a_
console.log(a.a)
```

You see we managed to change `a` via `b`. Same thing can happen with arrays;

```js
let a = [{a: 123}]; // Array is also object type
let b = a; // Same logic applies here, _b_ points to _a_ basically
b[0].a = 312;
console.log(a[0].a)
```

Comment: Adding to this, filter() only shallow copies the object into the new Array.

Answer (score 1):

That's because Arrays are non-primitives.

You need to imagine variable as wires to values. Every primitive type is imutable, so when you try to change the value of that variable, you change the "wire" that it points to, which is another unique value.
Every other non primitive value is mutable, so when you change the value of it, every other variable that is pointing to that value will now return that value changed.

If I do:

```
const fruit = { name: 'apple' } // {} creates a new value and points to it
const number = 1; // points to the primitive value 1
```

so if I do:

```
const anotherFruit = fruit;
anotherFruit.name = 'banana'; // changes the value of fruit

let anotherNumber = number;
number = 3; // value 1 is a primitive, so it can't be changed, will point to value 3
```

There's a small course by Dan Abramov that will make it easier for you to understand it: https://justjavascript.com